# How to use different datepickers using same function by passing parameters in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, android-layout, flutter-layout, flutter-test

Today I was working on a project and I found difficulty in making lots of datepickers using a single function in flutter. The code is as follows

```
import 'dart:ffi';

import 'package:AllInOneCalci/customAppBar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AgeCalcUI extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var AppBarHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: customAppBar(
        height: (AppBarHeight / 3) * 0.4,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 18.0),
              child: Text(
                'All In One Cali',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 35.0,
                    fontFamily: 'DancingScript',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: CustomDatePicker(),
    );
  }
}

class CustomDatePicker extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomDatePickerState createState() => _CustomDatePickerState();
}

class _CustomDatePickerState extends State<CustomDatePicker> {
  //getting the current date
  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();

  Future<void> selectDateTime(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime chosen = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: selectedDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(1700),
      lastDate: DateTime(2030),
      initialDatePickerMode: DatePickerMode.year,
    );
    if (chosen != null && chosen != selectedDate) {
      setState(() {
         selectedDate = chosen;
       });
    } 
  }

   //widget for displaying and choosing date onTap
  Widget CustomButtonDatePicker(Color ButtonColor, Color TextColor) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          "${selectedDate.toLocal()}".split(' ')[0],
          style: TextStyle(
            color: TextColor,
            fontSize: 30.0,
            fontFamily: 'DancingScript',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 18.0),
          child: MaterialButton(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
            elevation: 10.0,
            onPressed: () {
              selectDateTime(context);
            },
            color: ButtonColor,
            child: Text(
              'Select',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 15.0,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) / 2,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Spacer(),
          CustomButtonDatePicker(Colors.redAccent, Colors.cyan[200]),
          Spacer(),
          CustomButtonDatePicker(Colors.cyan[200], Colors.redAccent),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**I want to use the function selectDateTime() for both the date pickers but the data of both the pickers will be same. Can you please suggest me how to pass the function value for two date pickers without writing double codes for another selectdate as well**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try my code below :

```
class AgeCalcUI extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var AppBarHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("All In One Cali"),
      ),
      body: CustomDatePicker(),
    );
  }
}

enum DateSelection { first, second }

class CustomDatePicker extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomDatePickerState createState() => _CustomDatePickerState();
}

class _CustomDatePickerState extends State<CustomDatePicker> {
  //getting the current date
  DateTime selectedDateFirst = DateTime.now();
  DateTime selectedDateSecond = DateTime.now();
  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();

  Future<void> selectDateTime(
      BuildContext context, DateSelection dateSelection) async {
    final DateTime chosen = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: selectedDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(1700),
      lastDate: DateTime(2030),
      initialDatePickerMode: DatePickerMode.year,
    );
    if (chosen != null && chosen != selectedDate) {
      setState(() {
        switch (dateSelection) {
          case DateSelection.first:
            selectedDateFirst = chosen;

            break;

          case DateSelection.second:
            selectedDateSecond = chosen;

            break;
        }
      });
    }
  }

  //widget for displaying and choosing date onTap
  Widget CustomButtonDatePicker(
      DateSelection dateSelection, Color ButtonColor, Color TextColor) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          dateSelection == DateSelection.first
              ? "${selectedDateFirst.toLocal()}".split(' ')[0]
              : "${selectedDateSecond.toLocal()}".split(' ')[0],
          style: TextStyle(
            color: TextColor,
            fontSize: 30.0,
            fontFamily: 'DancingScript',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 18.0),
          child: MaterialButton(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
            elevation: 10.0,
            onPressed: () {
              selectDateTime(context, dateSelection);
            },
            color: ButtonColor,
            child: Text(
              'Select',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 15.0,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) / 2,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Spacer(),
          CustomButtonDatePicker(
              DateSelection.first, Colors.redAccent, Colors.cyan[200]),
          Spacer(),
          CustomButtonDatePicker(
              DateSelection.second, Colors.cyan[200], Colors.redAccent),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, Can you tell me how do I perform addition operation between these two Date Pickers?

Comment: Thank you for guiding me. I have done the same what you said. Waiting for your answer. Thank You once again sir